# Is it possible to decrypt files which were encrypted by gpg with a very strong password?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, gnupg

I have encrypted my important files by gpg with a 32-length password, includeing upper-case characters, numbers and some special characters.

I have stored them online so they can be download by hackers.

So if hackers can get my files, is it possible if they can decrypt my files without using a password?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, unless the hackers know of a very serious zero-day bug in GPG. However, if they keep the files for a few decades, it's possible that future computer hardware might eventually enable decryption -- only you know if that would be a concern for you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes*, the answer to such questions is always "yes*".

The real question however (and therefore the added "*"), is the amount of time it takes to do so. Since you've got a limited length and a limited amount of possible characters, you've also got a finite number of possible encryption keys.

You can calculate this using the following formula:

> number of combinations = password length<sup>number of available characters</sup>

So for example the latin alphabet has 26 characters. Add uppercase variants and numbers and you'll end up with 62 characters.

If the password uses 20 characters, you'd end up with:

> number of combinations = 20<sup>62</sup> = 4.6 * 10<sup>80</sup>

Rounded that's a 5 with 80 zeroes following it.

But even if you bruteforce the password, you're limited to a set amount of tries given a specific time frame.

All encryptions are really just "secure" based on the time it takes to decrypt them. It's impossible to create an encryption that can't be "hacked", unless there are multiple possible results (that appear as valid) and it's impossible to determine which is the correct one.

Comment: Nice attempt, but -1 for failing to follow up your sensationalism with practical guidance about what's possible currently in 2015 -- i.e., you didn't really answer the question.